Android App Crawler is not running with API 34
App Crawler is working perfectly with API 28 but not working with API 34
I use the same command:
java -jar crawl_launcher.jar --apk-file app-debug.apk --app-package-name com.example.myapplication --android-sdk $env:ANDROID_HOME

it is running perfectly with API 28 device but with API 34 device it immediately shows Crawl finished. without doing anything and shows Timed out waiting for crawl outputs proto file D:\app-crawler\crawl_output\app_firebase_test_lab\crawl_outputs.proto
command
